# visual basic web page code behind lost access to page elements

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a visual basic web site and in one of the pages, for some reason, when I view the codebehind, every reference to an element is underlined (using visual studio 2015) and gives me an " is not declared" message.  This just started today.  I have not made any changes to the code at all.  Here is a sample of what I have:

In my pay_web.aspx:

```
    <div id="container">
    <section class="banner_media_full page_banner" role="banner" id="banner">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="banner_full">
                <h1>Get Started</h1>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <article class="row" id="content">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblErrMsg" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim li As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Me.Page.Master.FindControl("liGS"), System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "current-menu-item")
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblErrMsg.Text = "!" & ex.Message.ToString()
    End Try
```

The element lblErrMsg is undefined, as far as code behind is concerned.

I am at a complete loss.  I can provide full page code if you want to see it.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why, but if I open my site in Visual Studio as administrator, I dont have this issue.  So, I will just open the site as administrator and move on.